# Jquery - Select a span's content inside of a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, dynamic

I am trying to select the content inside of a div but the CMS I am using adds this span inside of my div and so now I am not sure how to select the content inside of it. That span is used a couple times throughout the page. So I need to specifically select the one inside of this div.

This is the HTML.

```
<div id="emailAddress"><span merge-tag="{{user.email}}">CONTENT HERE IS WHAT THE VARIABLE SHOULD BE SET TO</span></div>
```

And I want to set it as the variable "emailAddress". So here is the full JQuery. Basically I am just showing/hiding content based on what my CMS puts in the div and span above.

```
var emailAddress = ????????????;

 $(document).ready(function() {

    if (emailAddress == 'email1@email.com') {
        $('#section1').show();
    } 

    else if (emailAddress == 'email2@email.com') {
        $('#section2').show();
    } 

    else if (emailAddress == 'email3@email.com') {
        $('#section3').show();
    } 

    else {
        $('#default-content').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Uh, you can get the text with either `html()` or `text()` off of the `$('#emailAddress span')`.  What are you confused about?  Searching for how to select text of an element should return pre-existing answers already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```js
var emailAddress = null;

 $(document).ready(function() {
    emailAddress = $('#emailAddress span').text();
    console.log(emailAddress);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="emailAddress"><span merge-tag="{{user.email}}">CONTENT HERE IS WHAT THE VARIABLE SHOULD BE SET TO</span></div>
```

Comment: So should it look like this? It's not working. I think I am missing something. https://codepen.io/AmyMontgomery/pen/BrzKBg